# Loop through multidimensional Json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a multilevel JSon and need to loop through and get its column name and value.

```
 var json   {  
       "Students":[  
          {  
             "name":{  
                "value":"Allan"
             },
             "number":{  
                "value":"123"
             }
          },
          {  
             "name":{  
                "value":"Frank"
             },
             "number":{  
                "value":"456"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

I can loop through and get the column name but cannot get the value.

```
var objectKeys = Object.keys(json); 
for (var key in objectKeys)
    {       
        var student = json.Students;

        for (var i = 0; i < student .length; i++) {

            for (var column in json.Students[i])
                {

                window.print(column);
                window.print(column.value);                                         

            }

        }       
}
```

The above gives me the following

```
name
undefined
number
undefined
name
undefined
number
undefined
```

Ideally i want to treat one row separately so i can insert it in database, like insert Allan and 123 against name and number column of students table.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Read and enjoy: [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var objectKeys = Object.keys(json);
for (var key in objectKeys)
{       
    var student = json.Students;

    for (var i = 0; i < student .length; i++) {

        for (var column in json.Students[i]) {
            window.print(column);
            window.print(json.Students[i][column].value);

        }

    }
}
```

since `key` in outer for loop isn't used it is redundant

Answer (score 0):

```
var objectKeys = Object.keys(json); 
for (var key in objectKeys) {       
    var student = json.Students;
    for (var i = 0; i < student .length; i++) {
        window.print(json.Students[i].name.value);
        window.print(json.Students[i].number.value);

    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jero for your input, i am not allowed to mark your answer as useful because i do not have enough points but displayName solution was more dynamic as i didn't have to specify the column name hence marked that as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object contains 1 entry with **key** Students and **value** of a list of 2 dictionaries.

so `var objectKeys = Object.keys(json);` 
represents just one value **"Students"**

It doesn't look like you're using the `var key in objectKeys` as you instantiate this variable **key** but never use it.

Re-write your code like this if your intent is to loop through the dictionary:

```
 var json   {  
       "Students":[  
          {  
             "name":{  
                "value":"Allan"
             },
             "number":{  
                "value":"123"
             }
          },
          {  
             "name":{  
                "value":"Frank"
             },
             "number":{  
                "value":"456"
             }
          }
       ]
    }

for(let i = 0; i < json["Students"].length; i++){

    let key_values = Object.keys(json["Students"][i]);

    for(let inner_key_values in key_values){
        window.print(json["Students"][i][inner_key_values].value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below snippet for you - It prints a nested object recursively. You can modify it as you want.

```
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3",
    "p4": {
        "p4": 'value 4'
    }
};



/**
*   Printing a nested javascript object
*/
function jsonPrinter(obj) {

    for (let key in obj) {
        // checking if it's nested
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && (typeof obj[key] === "object")) {
            jsonPrinter(obj[key])
        } else {
            // printing the flat attributes
            console.log(key + " -> " + obj[key]);
        }
    }
}

jsonPrinter(p);
```